# Time Based Polling in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I am using the `Date()` object to make a alarm.I am trying to make an alarm clock. I want a function to execute when the time from the date object reaches the time that the user sets

The user sets the alarm by selecting a specific time. Where I am stuck is that I want to poll until the user selected time equals the system time. I tried using `setTimeout()` but getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
function showTime(){
            var e = document.getElementById("hourSelect");
            var hour = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            var e1 = document.getElementById("autoDropDown");
            var minuteSelected = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;
            var e2 = document.getElementById("amPmSelect");
            var AMPM = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;
            }
```

so that's where I am getting my alarm time. So what do I use to check if this time equals the System Time (which I obtained using `Date()` object.

```
var today = new Date();
        var hours = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        var suffix = (hours >= 12)? 'pm' : 'am';    //converting military time to non-military time.
        hours = (hours > 12)? hours -12 : hours;
        hours = (hours == '00')? 12 : hours;
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
```

P.S: I took care of data mismatch, converted the time into a number. And also converted everything to normal time instead of Military time.

Comment: Could you show us where you execute the `setTimeout` function?

Comment: `<html>
<body>
 <script>
 var UST = "42";




  var today = new Date();
  var ST = today.getMinutes();

  while (true) {
   setTimeout(alarm(),5000)

   if (parseInt(UST) == ST){
    

    alert("BEEEP");
    break
   }
  }

  function alarm(){
   console.log("waitng")
   ;}


  </script>
 </body>
 </html>`

Answer (score 0):

```
var alarm = new Date(2017,00,25,14,9,01);

var checktime = function(){ 
var date = new Date();
if(alarm.getHours() === date.getHours()){
    if(alarm.getMinutes() === date.getMinutes()){
            if(alarm.getMinutes() === date.getMinutes()){
                console.log('trigger');
                return true;
            }
    }
  return false;  
};
};

 var interval = setInterval(function(){
     if(checktime()){
         clearInterval(interval);
         console.log('cleared');
     };
 },100);
```

You can use setInterval and keep checking to see if the time matches after you select the alarm time. After the times matche, you can trigger your function. Also have it clearInterval after the trigger.